# Init a class from my second view with data from the first

Tags: swiftui

In my initial ContentView() I have a button that presents a UIImagePicker, when an image is chosen I then navigate to SecondView where I can view the image and it’s data from UIImagePickerController.InfoKey

I currently have an ImageManager class that’s set as an EnviromentObject that I pass the InfoKey to that then sets up all the variables in that class — it works but this feels messy.

What I’d like to do is init the ImageManager class when I navigate to SecondView as that’s the only view that needs that data.

I’d tried passing the InfoKey as a variable:

```
@State var InfoKey: [IImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]

SecondView(key: self.infoKey)
```

but this crashes because I don’t have any data until an image is chosen

What would be the best way to tackle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@State` must have initial value, so use just empty container

```
@State var infoKey: [IImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any] = [:]
```

then pass it in `SecondView` as binding

```
SecondView(key: self.$infoKey)
```

where

```
struct SecondView: View {
    @Binding var key: [IImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]
```